# How to use MySQL IF from PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to find in the internet how to use IF inside SQL command in PHP, but I could find a good tutorial.

So I want to make it

```
SELECT *,(neutral_kills*0.5 + rival_kills)/deaths AS totalkdr
FROM sc_players
ORDER BY totalkdr DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

But I want to put `IF (deaths == 0){deaths + 1}`

How can I do it?

Comment: What? I cannot understand what you are asking. Please rephrase.

Comment: What do you have so far? Any code?

Comment: Use a `CASE` statement

Comment: Why did you add the iframe tag?

Comment: It's not nice to rewrite your question to something completely different after people have started to comment.

Comment: @Barmar - on the contrary, the poster has attempted to clarify and develop their original question as requested.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The original question was something about ranks, now it's about using IF to prevent division by zero. That's why it got closed as a duplicate of the `Mysql rank function` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is used like a function:

```
SELECT *,(neutral_kills*0.5 + rival_kills)/IF(deaths = 0, 1, deaths) AS totalkdr
FROM sc_players
ORDER BY totalkdr DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/bloodcra/public_html/pvp/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 94  Not working ):

Comment: I fixed the unbalanced parentheses. If you're getting that error, it means you're not correctly checking for errors from `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Actually, the error was that I wrote `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Yes, Its working now. Thanks, there is my rank: www.bloodcraft.com.br/pvp/rank